# Как создать партицию из запроса в MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, mariadb, partition

Есть таблица которую надо партицировать. Но, ее критерий партицирования находятся в другой таблице. Пытаюсь сделать что-то типа этого:

```
ALTER TABLE example 
PARTITION BY list(id) (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (select t.id from table1 t where YEAR(t.date)='2015'),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Это невозможно. Если партиционируемая таблица и таблица с нужным атрибутом связаны 1:1, переносите атрибут в партиционируемую таблицу (возможно, идя на переопределение данных ради профита от партиций). Если иначе - имеет место неразрешимая неоднозначность.

Comment: @akina, а может есть другие способы это решить? Я пробовал через view, но она не поддерживает триггеры. Как в PostgreSQL, наследовании нет :(

Comment: А зачем вам понадобилось партиционирование по таким спискам id ?

Comment: @tuzhsya_tuzhsya Может, лучше озвучить задачу, а не Вашу идею, как её решать? тем более что идея-то нежизнеспособненькая...